# Rails Devise: Set password reset token and redirect user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, login-control

In my app for a certain use case I create a new user (programmatically set the password) and send them a confirmation email.

I would like them to be able to change their password immediately after confirming (without having to enter the system generated one which I don't want to send them)

In effect I would like
1)  System creates a new user account with generated password.
2)  System sends confirmation email.
3)  User clicks confirmation and is redirected to enter in their password (effectively send them to a URL like below)

```
<a href="http://localhost:3000/users/password/edit?reset_password_token=v5Q3oQGbsyqAUUxyqLtb">Change my password</a>
```

Any help / pointers would be great.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

A simple way to have just one step for users to confirm email address and set initial password using the link you proposed...

Send one email your app generates, including a reset_password_token, and consider user's possession of that token confirmation of the validity of that email address.

In system account generation code, assuming User model is set up with :recoverable and :database_authenticatable Devise modules...

```rb
acct = User.new
acct.password = User.reset_password_token #won't actually be used...  
acct.reset_password_token = User.reset_password_token 
acct.email = "user@usercompany.com" #assuming users will identify themselves with this field
#set other acct fields you may need
acct.save
```

Make the devise reset password view a little clearer for users when setting initial password.

### views/devise/passwords/edit.html.erb

```
...
<%= "true" == params[:initial] ? "Set your password" : "Reset your password" %>
...
```

### Generated Email

```html
Hi <%= @user.name %>
An account has been generated for you.
Please visit www.oursite.com/users/password/edit?initial=true&reset_password_token=<%= @user.reset_password_token %> to set your password.
```

No need to include :confirmable Devise module in your User model, since accounts created by your app won't get accessed without the reset_password_token in the email.

Devise will handle the submit and clear the reset_password_token field.

See `devise_gem_folder/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb` and `database_authenticatable.rb` for details on `reset_password_token` method and friends.

If you want to use Devise `:confirmable` module rather than this approach,  see the [Devise wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation).

Comment: Thanks very much - hadn't seen that wiki as it has just been created.  Like the idea of the password reset token automatically being proof of being confirmed.  Neat.

Comment: yeah, this is a great workflow for many rails apps. I was trying to figure out how my app can initiate the password reset (generate new token). Nicely documented.

Comment: BTW I also had to set user.reset_password_sent_at to Time.now or else the password links were 'expired'

Comment: It seems that `reset_password_token` [has been removed from the Recoverable model](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/commit/d75fd56f150f006aee51dcafc7157454190de570). This means `User.reset_password_token` will throw a wobbly in later versions of Devise. I think you can achieve something similar with `Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :reset_password_token)` where `User` is the name of your Devise model. But happier to be told there's a more succinct way.

Answer (score 33):

In Rails 4.1, the following modification of Anatortoise House's reply works:

```
user = User.new
user.password = SecureRandom.hex #some random unguessable string
raw_token, hashed_token = Devise.token_generator.generate(User, :reset_password_token)
user.reset_password_token = hashed_token
user.reset_password_sent_at = Time.now.utc
user.email = 'user@usercompany.com'
user.save!
# Use a mailer you've written, such as:
AccountMailer.set_password_notice(user, raw_token).deliver
```

The email view has this link:

```
www.oursite.com/users/password/edit?initial=true&reset_password_token=<%= @raw_token %>
```

Comment: Where does the method `set_password_notice` come from?  I've configured a custom mailer that inherits from Devise::Mailer but getting a method not found error

Comment: You would have to define it yourself, just as any other ordinary out-going email, using ActionMailer.

Comment: As of Devise version 3.5.1 the reset_password_token will be cleared in any call that also changes the email or password. https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb

Comment: As of Devise version 3.5.1 the reset_password_token  will be cleared in any call that also changes the user email or password https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/recoverable.rb so you'll need ot set the reset_password_token and reset_password_sent_at values in a separate user.save call

Answer (score 3):

Here is my snippet for mailer preview

```
class Devise::MailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  def reset_password_instructions
    user = User.last
    token = user.send(:set_reset_password_token)
    Devise::Mailer.reset_password_instructions(user, token)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can call

```
user.send(:set_reset_password_token)
```

It may not be stable, as it's a protected method but it can work for your case. Just cover it with a test.

(tested on Devise v. 3.4)