# Rails devise reset_password_token keeps getting marked as "expired"

Tags: devise, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm trying to use devise's reset_password_token to force users to change their password when they log in for the first time, using what I read here: [Rails Devise: Set password reset token and redirect user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5894191/rails-devise-set-password-reset-token-and-redirect-user)

I get as far as a page loading that says "set your password", but every time I hit submit, there's a notice that says that the reset_password_token has expired and to request a new one. I've tried setting reset_password_token to a variable instead of accessing via the user object (@user.reset_password_token), in case expiration is calculated by if that token was accessed, but it still says it's expired when I try to set my initial password.  I'm not sure how expiration is calculated, anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Found the answer!

When a reset_password_token is generated, `@user.reset_password_sent_at`
needs to be set to Time.now, or else when devise runs
`@user.reset_password_period_valid?` to find out if the reset token is
still valid, it will get nil and assume the token has expired.